# How to draw these subtler but standard emojis in monochrome

Tags: icon, design-principles, emoji

I'm looking at [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_emoticons) and [this](https://pc.net/emoticons/) for basic text emoticons, and some of the standard *graphical* ones we use today aren't really easily done in text, and don't seem easy to do in monochrome without the use of gradients.

I'm wondering if one could offer some suggestions how to potentially convert the following standard emojis to something monochrome (and gradientless, i.e. basic vector).

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

You'll notice on the Wiki link that many of these have close variants that are doable in plain ascii, but I selected the ones that I thought would be harder. Specifically, the long tears, the hearts, the blushing, the subtle happy eyes. I am in particular wondering about for small resolution, like what you see when you paste an emoji here for example: ☺️. Maybe a little bit larger, that's pretty small. It's the gradients mostly that make it seem difficult, as well as the intricate detail in some of them.

If I try to draw the first one in monochrome it looks like a clown :'(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't really understand.. remove color and gradients. Set all paths to black.. you have a monochrome emoji. Each and every one of your samples could easily be reduced to white fills with black strokes and maintain the "emotion".

[image]

<sub>(Redrawn in about 2 minutes...)</sub>

Comment: But the blush and such.

Comment: The gradients, while conveying some mood, are not the primary visual factor. At least to me. You simply are not going to pull off subtle gradients without gradients. Stippling or crosshatching, common ways to indicate value in solid color, won't work at the small size.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe you can do that without some degree of compromise, but if you're looking for ideas, see [this link](https://thenounproject.com/search/?q=emoji) which lists different emoji styles in vector (SVG) format, maybe one of these could work.